# Using http.get to get page from frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak, angular8, angular-http

It's possible to use Angular 8 `http.get` to get a page from the frontend itself ?

My local frontend URL: https://192.168.0.177:4200/

I tried in a service:

```
test(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
        .get<string>(`https://192.168.0.177:4200/ping`)
        .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
}
```

but I got a 404:

Console:

```
GET https://192.168.0.177:4200/ping 404 (Not Found)
ERROR 404 - Not Found <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /ping</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This has an hardcoded url because it's just a test. My FE is on port 4200 and my backend in 3443.

https://192.168.0.177:4200/ping url load correctly if I put it directly on browser.

The /ping url is an Angular component with only a `PING` string inside:

ping.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ping',
    templateUrl: './ping.component.html'
})
export class PingComponent {

    constructor() { }
}
```

ping.component.html:

```
PING
```

I call service.test() from some other component this way:

```
test(): void {
    this.myService.test().subscribe(test=>{
        console.log('test', test); // Should result in PING
    })
}
```

I also tried with axios:

```
    axios.get('https://192.168.0.177:4200/ping').then(ping=>{
        console.log('ping', ping);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('ping error', err);
    });
```

with same result.

What I'm trying to do here ? I am developing an Angular video application that shows live video stream that take too long. It has a Keycloak login that has an idle limit. So I'm trying to simulate user action in order to make keycloak know it's alive and don't logout automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing an url from a CSR application, when you access `/ping` from a browser, the angular router maps that internal route to see your component, but when you access directly through an HTTP request it gets 404 because that path does not exist as a static page (its rendered in the browser), and the request "cant" run JS to apply the angular router to it.

Did you try to convert your application to Angular Universal (SSR)?, that way you will have a NodeJS server that will respond with the dynamic HTML of `/ping` when you request it through HTTP (if that suits you, of course).

Comment: I see... I must find other way to simulate user action then. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you make some rest request to refresh the session behind the scenes?. Have you seen the https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular module?, it has a function to `check-sso` using a hidden iframe, maybe it can help you

Comment: In keycloak-angular, the KeycloakService has a updateToken() which might be what you are looking for. Check out this example provided by them https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular#keycloak-js-events

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I'm using that exact library. I can't use check-sso because it's a corporative server and I need to access their page to login not only with passwords but with token certificates. Their server is who sends the user details to me. So I can't do a silent login.

Comment: @TanJooHong About updateToken() I'm already using it, but it's not a question of updating then token. That is working correctly. But even with regular token updates the application is still considered idle to the server. I have to generate some user activity.

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I'll try to get some data from the backend to see if that counts as "activity"

Comment: @Nelson perfect!, let me know if that works. If not, what else count as an “user activity”?, just “play” with the UI?